# How to check the length of a number in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm begginer on Sql.

I created a table with a field of phone:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (

phone NUMBER(9),

)
```

Now I have to set a CHECK to delimite the lenght of digits to the number var, to allow you to only enter a 9-digit number and no more or less.

I try:

```
ALTER TABLE contact ADD CONSTRAINT CK_phone_right check (length(phone) < 9)
```

But it doesn't work, because it converts number format to string.

How to do it to keep number type and check it to 9 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store a phone as a number.  Use a string instead.  If it has to be exactly 9 digits, then:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
    phone CHAR(9),
    constraint chk_contact_phone check ( regexp_like(phone, '^[0-9]{9}$') )
)
```

A phone number is not really a number.  A number is something you can do arithmetic on.  Also, it is possible for a phone number to start with `0`.

Comment: check Gordon`s regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can put phone number as varchar2 or char type and check the phone number by regular expression:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
   phone CHAR(9),
   constraint valid_phone_number 
   CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(phone, 'd{9}$'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Alter Table  Empsu ADD CONSTRAINT len CHECK (LENGTH(PH_No) =10);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?